# How to sort this in assending order? i have got Object[]

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

How do I convert `Object[]` to array and sort it in ascending order? `Array` object needs to be created then we can use `Arrays.sort();` please suggest to sort in ascending order

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import sun.security.util.Length;

public class JavaInterview{

        public static void main(String a[]){
            int[] arr1 = {4,7,3,9,2};
            int[] arr2 = {3,2,12,9,40,32,4};
          Set hashSet= new HashSet<Integer>();

                for(int i= 0; i<arr1.length; i++) hashSet.add(arr1[i]);
                for (int i=0 ; i<arr2.length; i++) hashSet.add(arr2[i]);
          //Converting into Array   
            Object[] obj=   hashSet.toArray();
            for (int i=0; i<obj.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(obj[i]);

            }

        }                  

}
```

Comment: What in the world is that internal import doing there?

Comment: "How do I convert Object[] to array" - that *is* an array...

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) and the collection will sort for you. And the generic type goes on the left. Something like,

```
int[] arr1 = { 4, 7, 3, 9, 2 };
int[] arr2 = { 3, 2, 12, 9, 40, 32, 4 };
Set<Integer> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();

for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
    treeSet.add(arr1[i]);
for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++)
    treeSet.add(arr2[i]);
Integer[] arr = treeSet.toArray(new Integer[0]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Output is

```
[2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 12, 32, 40]
```

If you can use the object wrapper types, you could eliminate the loops by using `addAll` and [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) like

```
Integer[] arr1 = { 4, 7, 3, 9, 2 };
Integer[] arr2 = { 3, 2, 12, 9, 40, 32, 4 };
Set<Integer> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();
treeSet.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr1));
treeSet.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr2));
Integer[] arr = treeSet.toArray(new Integer[0]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

For the same output as before.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help Elliott Frisch... This works.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Set;


public class Sorting{

        public static void main(String a[]){
            int[] arr1 = {4,7,3,9,2};
            int[] arr2 = {3,2,12,9,40,32,4};
        //first sort your array
        Arrays.sort(arr1);
        Arrays.sort(arr2);
        //then use LinkedHashSet to store because it maintains order
          Set hashSet= new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();

                for(int i= 0; i<arr1.length; i++) hashSet.add(arr1[i]);
                for (int i=0 ; i<arr2.length; i++) hashSet.add(arr2[i]);
          //Converting into Array   
            Object[] obj=   hashSet.toArray();
            for (int i=0; i<obj.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(obj[i]);

            }

        }                  

}
```

Is it helpful to you?